# How to generate swagger-ui from several yaml specifications?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I have a spring boot application that generates 2 APIs from 2 specification files. I can generate a `swagger-ui` page for one of them by adding

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/firstAPI.yaml
```

to `application.properties`. But how can I include the second API?

I tried:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls=/firstAPI.yaml,/secondAPI.yaml
```

That creates a combined `http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs/` but at `http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs/` despite being able to choose between both specs in the top bar, the page says "Failed to load API definition" for both.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Springdoc with multiple api-docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63675544/springdoc-with-multiple-api-docs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the property `urls`:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[0].name = first
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[0].url = /firstAPI.yaml

springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[1].name = second
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[1].url = /secondAPI.yaml
```

You can find this property in the [documentation](https://springdoc.org/springdoc-properties.html#swagger-ui-properties). There is also a nice [FAQ](https://springdoc.org/faq.html#how-can-i-agreagte-external-endpoints-exposing-openapi-3-spec-inside-one-single-application) for this question:

> The properties springdoc.swagger-ui.urls.*, are suitable to configure external (/v3/api-docs url). For example if you want to agreagte all the endpoints of other services, inside one single application. Don’t forget that CORS needs to be enabled as well.